# unblock activex just for one local html page

Tags: internet-explorer, activex

I have a local html page that will run in IE 8 (need to use it because of an application dependent on it) and want to **unblock activex just for this local web page**.

How could I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using Intranet or Trusted Sites zones for anything else, you can throw the page in one of those zones and enable ActiveX for the zone.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Hyppy. Do you know what is the syntax to add a local html page to the trusted sites?

Comment: It's whatever you put in the address bar to access it. If you're speaking of localhost, it would be http://localhost.

Comment: Thank you Hyppy. Added the path but I still get the bar. Going to try some more variations.